# Python: Replacing multiple words with a random choice

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, random

I have a phrase with some special marked words which I want to replace. These words match a key in a dictionary, which has a list of words that I want to randomly choose to replace with.

I'm wondering if there's a better way to go about doing this, or is what I have seem like a valid approach? I have a feeling there may be a smarter way with `lambda` but I'm not sure.

Hopefully the code explains for itself!

```
import random

words = {"fruit":["apples", "bananas", "oranges"], 
         "veggies":["broccoli", "corn", "cucumbers"]}

txt = "I'm not in a mood for [veggies], I rather have [fruit], and [fruit]."

for key in words:
    target_word = "[{0}]".format(key)

    while target_word in txt:
        txt = txt.replace(target_word, random.choice(words[key]), 1)
```

Running it a few times will randomly output:

> I'm not in a mood for corn, I rather have bananas, and apples.
>
> I'm not in a mood for broccoli, I rather have oranges, and bananas.
>
> I'm not in a mood for cucumbers, I rather have apples, and oranges.
>
> ..and so on..

I should mention that there could be any number of keys in `words`, and any number of marked words in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub` also accepts a callable as `repl` argument:

```
In [19]: import random, re
    ...: 
    ...: words = {"fruit":["apples", "bananas", "oranges"], 
    ...:          "veggies":["broccoli", "corn", "cucumbers"]}
    ...: 
    ...: txt = "I'm not in a mood for [veggies], I rather have [fruit], and [fruit]."
    ...: 

In [20]: regex = re.compile(r'\[({})\]'.format('|'.join(words)))

In [21]: regex.pattern
Out[21]: '\\[(fruit|veggies)\\]'

In [22]: regex.sub(lambda match: random.choice(words[match.group(1)]), txt)
Out[22]: "I'm not in a mood for broccoli, I rather have bananas, and apples."

In [23]: regex.sub(lambda match: random.choice(words[match.group(1)]), txt)
Out[23]: "I'm not in a mood for corn, I rather have oranges, and oranges."
```

I think that it's against Python Zen though.

Comment: Thanks, though I like what you came up with I do somewhat agree with Python Zen. Maybe it's best to just stick with what I have then.

Comment: @GreenCell Yes, but re.sub is faster. It do worth it if speed really matters.

Answer (score 1):

i done it using `re.findall` then `str.replace`, but i feel its not really much better than yours either

```
import random

words = {"fruit":["apples", "bananas", "oranges"], 
         "veggies":["broccoli", "corn", "cucumbers"]}
txt = "I'm not in a mood for [veggies], I rather have [fruit], and [fruit]."

found = re.findall('\[\w+\]', txt)
for m in found:
    txt = txt.replace(m, random.choice(words.get(m.strip('[]'), [m])), 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be one way of doing it:

```
import random

words = {"fruit":["apples", "bananas", "oranges"], 
         "veggies":["broccoli", "corn", "cucumbers"]}

txt = "I'm not in a mood for [veggies], I rather have [fruit]."    
txt = txt.replace('[veggies]', random.choice(words['veggies'])).replace('[fruit]', random.choice(words['fruit']))
```

Comment: This would, however, lose dynamism. The example picks words to replace from dictionary keys, your answer hardcodes them as fruit and veggies.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but like Hannu said, this is hard coded. I edited my question to clarify that.